# First MVC project with dynamic form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm starting in MVC, coming from Web Forms, and I decided to make a recipes website for my first project.
I chose database first approach because that's what the company where I work does and it seems that although code first is favored among developers, database first is in fact what most companies do.

So with my "Create" view I already can create a new recipe with title, description, time and so on.
But I'm stuck with the first challenge: dynamically add steps to the recipe.

I think I could make it work with [FormCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection(v=vs.118).aspx) but I'm lost with what I have to do in controller action and view form. I could make it work purely with JavaScript but I'd have to to hard code all the HTML for labels, inputs and data validation instead of using Razor and all it's benefits.

[This is my database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7zJp.jpg). Highlighted in red so you can easily see what I'm trying to do.

Recipe.cs auto generated by EF (ReceitaPasso = RecipeStep):

```
public partial class Receita
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Receita()
    {
        this.ReceitaImagem = new HashSet<ReceitaImagem>();
        this.ReceitaIngrediente = new HashSet<ReceitaIngrediente>();
        this.ReceitaNota = new HashSet<ReceitaNota>();
        this.ReceitaPasso = new HashSet<ReceitaPasso>();
        this.ReceitaTag = new HashSet<ReceitaTag>();
    }

    public int ReceitaID { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ReceitaTipoID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ReceitaGastronomiaID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ReceitaDificuldadeID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ReceitaCustoID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> TempoTotal { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> TempoPreparacao { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> TempoCozedura { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Doses { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Flag { get; set; }
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DosesUnidadeID { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data { get; set; }

    public virtual ReceitaCusto ReceitaCusto { get; set; }
    public virtual ReceitaDificuldade ReceitaDificuldade { get; set; }
    public virtual ReceitaGastronomia ReceitaGastronomia { get; set; }
    public virtual ReceitaTipo ReceitaTipo { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ReceitaImagem> ReceitaImagem { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ReceitaIngrediente> ReceitaIngrediente { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ReceitaNota> ReceitaNota { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ReceitaPasso> ReceitaPasso { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ReceitaTag> ReceitaTag { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DosesUnidade DosesUnidade { get; set; }
}
```

I didn't add anything to the controller (and was surprised EF did all the SelectLists for me, amazing!) but here it is:

```
// GET: Receitas/Create
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.ReceitaCustoID = new SelectList(db.ReceitaCusto.OrderBy(x => x.ReceitaCustoID), "ReceitaCustoID", "Descricao");
    ViewBag.ReceitaDificuldadeID = new SelectList(db.ReceitaDificuldade.OrderBy(x => x.ReceitaDificuldadeID), "ReceitaDificuldadeID", "Descricao");
    ViewBag.ReceitaGastronomiaID = new SelectList(db.ReceitaGastronomia.OrderBy(x => x.Descricao), "ReceitaGastronomiaID", "Descricao");
    ViewBag.ReceitaTipoID = new SelectList(db.ReceitaTipo.OrderBy(x => x.Descricao), "ReceitaTipoID", "Descricao");
    ViewBag.DosesUnidadeID = new SelectList(db.DosesUnidade.OrderBy(x => x.Descricao), "DosesUnidadeID", "Descricao");

    return View("Create", "_MainLayout");
}
```

And for the view I was trying to do something like:

```
<div class="row">
@foreach (var passo in Model.ReceitaPasso)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => passo.Descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => passo.Descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => passo.Descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

But I get an NullReferenceException in Model.ReceitaPasso, probably because I should pass something to the view.

So, any guidance?

EDIT: It seems that if this was to edit the recipe itself, I would've a partial view with the steps and that should be easy to implement. In this case I don't have a RecipeID (ReceitaID) yet, and that's been the challenge for me right now.

Comment: Add the @models to your view, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752749/different-between-model-and-model let me know if it helps

Comment: @Haris in my view, where the HTML markup above is, I have `@model Calorias.Models.Receita`. From what I've googled it seems that it's possible to have multiple models per view but maybe there is a more "correct" approach of doing dynamic forms.

Comment: I would research MVC ViewModels. Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124273/model-with-child-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: Well... @SteveGreene I just googled "MVC ViewModels dynamic form" and the [FIRST link is a SO question with the EXACT same problem/example I'm facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314058/mvc-3-dynamic-form-using-a-viewmodel). So maybe that is the way to go. I'll dive more deep into it and try a few things. Meanwhile if there's anymore or better tips I'm all ears. Thank you.

Comment: We use jquery modal popups for this kind of thing (adding/editing child collections). That is more of an MVC 201 thing. Tools like Kendo UI (there are many others) make this painless.

Comment: u get null reference on Post Or Get .?

Comment: @SyedMunisAli on Get.  I already had Get and Post working with basic elements of a recipe, like title, description, time to cook, etc. but when I added the code mentioned in my original question I got that error. But really the point here is not the error, but the approach to overcome the challenge of this dynamic form in particular.

Comment: add this also to your create controller and try to run let me perfectly examine ! because here we cant run your code so !  ` ViewBag.ReceitaPasso = new SelectList(db.ReceitaPasso.OrderBy(x => x.Descricao), "ReceitalID", "Descricao"); `